# Snowflake Profile Does Not Match Explain

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have found a scenario where the query `EXPLAIN` output does not match what's shown under the "Profile" tab of a completed query. There may be a simpler query to reproduce these results, but I haven't found it. What I've found, is if you join multiple `WITH` statements, and one of those `WITH` statements contains a `UNION`, the `EXPLAIN` will correctly display the pruned fields on the `Table Scan` step, but the Profile will not.

Here are some examples of both working and bugged queries:

```
-- Join On Union. No With (Good)
SELECT COUNT(*) as "count", RANDOM() cb 
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM tpch_sf100.customer t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM tpch_sf100.customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM tpch_sf100.customer
    ) t2 ON t1.c_custkey = t2.c_custkey
)

-- Join On Union. Using With (Good)
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS "count", RANDOM() cb 
FROM (
    WITH t1 AS (
        SELECT * FROM tpch_sf100.customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM tpch_sf100.customer
    )
    SELECT * FROM tpch_sf100.customer t2
    JOIN t1 on t1.c_custkey = t2.c_custkey
)

-- Join On Union. Multiple Withs (Bugged)
EXPLAIN SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS "count", RANDOM() cb 
FROM (
    WITH t1 AS (
        SELECT * FROM tpch_sf100.customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM tpch_sf100.customer
    ), t2 AS (
        SELECT * FROM tpch_sf100.customer
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM t1
    JOIN t2 on t1.c_custkey = t2.c_custkey
)
```

For the "Good" queries, the explain and profile both correctly show that only the `c_custkey` field is fetched in the table scans.

Explain:
[image: Explain]

Profile:
[image: Profile]

But with the last "Bugged" query, the explain shows correctly that only `c_custkey` was used, but the profile does not.

Explain:
[image: Explain]

Profile:
[image: Profile]

I think this is a visual bug in the profile, but would like someone to confirm or explain why these two are different. And if it's true that the query did actually pull back those additional unused fields, why does that step show it scanned the same amount of data as other queries that didn't pull back extra fields?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior on multiple deployments. There's probably a slight difference in the SQL parsing, but the `explain` looks right.